# Trying to remove subview from another class

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following function for creating a overlay/subview on top of my view:

```
func testOverLay(shouldShow: Bool){

    let iconImageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        iv.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        return iv

    }()
    let blueCover = UIView(frame: iconImageView.frame)
    blueCover.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    blueCover.layer.opacity = 0.3
    blueCover.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    blueCover.tag = 100

    let navshadowImage: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        iv.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.width, height: self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height + statusBarHeight!)
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        return iv

    }()
    let navBlackCover = UIView(frame: navshadowImage.frame)
    navBlackCover.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    navBlackCover.layer.opacity = 0.3
    navBlackCover.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    navBlackCover.tag = 200

    if shouldShow{
        view.addSubview(blueCover)
        self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(navBlackCover)

    }else{
        removeSubview(firstTag: 100, secondTag: 200)
    }
}
```

I'm removing it by calling `removeSubview`:

```
func removeSubview(firstTag: Int, secondTag: Int){
    print("removeSubview was called")
    if let viewWithTag = self.view.viewWithTag(firstTag) {
        viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    if let viewWithTag = self.navigationController?.view.viewWithTag(secondTag){
        viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()

    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine when I'm calling it from the same class.

---

But I wanted to call it from another class. I created a delegate to be able to call the function, then I call it from my second class like this:

```
model.removeSubview(firstTag: 100, secondTag: 200)
```

But for some reason the view doesn't get removed.

The function does get called from my "second class", I can see the print statement in my console.

I'm not sure if the tag gets removed when I create a different class?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the second class? How do you create the model?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR the second class is a `UIViewController` and I create the model by declaring `let model = ViewController()` then calling `model.mDelegate = self` inside `viewDidLoad`.  `ViewController()` refers to my first class

Comment: What is the relation between these 2 view controllers?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR  When the `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` is pressed, I display the second viewholder(only 80% of `self.view.frame.width`) , when it is pressed again the second view controller is "hidden" again. I would now like to display a shadow on top of the first view controller and hide it again.